# Mocking a specific class instance of an interface

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm trying to mock out `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity`.  However, I specifically want to replace a particular `Claim` during the test.  The problem that I have is that whilst I can mock out and substitute elements of the interface, I don't have access to the class until it is resolved and cast inside the method.

Here's my Controller constructor:

```
public MyController(IIdentity identity)
{
    _userIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

And here is my code where I'm trying to mock out the claims:

```
var mockClaim = new Claim("test", "test");

IIdentity identity = Substitute.For<IIdentity>();
((ClaimsIdentity)identity).Claims.Returns(new List<Claim>() { mockClaim });
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, because `identity` isn't actually an IIdentity in this case.  Although I am asking a specific question relating to this problem, my more general question is: are there any techniques for mocking a specific class instance of an interface within the interface mock?

(I realise that I can simply wrap this whole lot up in my own interface and wrapper class - but that feels like overkill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock `ClaimsIdentity` in this case, not `IIdentity`. Of course you will be able to pass resuling mock to controller, because `ClaimsIdentity` implements `IIdentity`:

```
var identity = Substitute.For<ClaimsIdentity>();
identity.Claims.Returns(new List<Claim>() { mockClaim });
var controller = new MyController(identity);
// ...
```